# PL/PgSQL: Catching unique violation exceptions and inserting from 'record' variables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I've got a nightly archive job that sweeps existing rows from a `records` table into `records_archive`:

```
INSERT INTO records_archive 
    SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > 555 AND id <= 556;
```

For reasons that are outside the scope of this question, there is a column -- `master_guid` -- in both `records` and `records_archive` that has a `UNIQUE` index, and I can't change that.  Rebuilding the index into a non-unique one is off the table for reasons out of my control.  So, in principle, every `master_guid` value is supposed to be unique.  There are some bad client implementations out there that sometimes fail to generate unique enough GUIDs, though, which results in a collision when we attempt to insert a record into `records_archive` that with a `master_guid` value that already exists in `records_archive`.

I can't fix the clients, so I need to work around it.  The way to do that is to catch the `unique_violation` exception, modify the GUID (adding some random characters to it), and attempt to re-insert.

I can't just wrap the above-mentioned `INSERT` query in a stored procedure and catch the `unique_violation` exception, because the whole query is one transaction.  I need row-level access.  So, I wrote a stored procedure to iterate over each row and catch a `unique_violation` exception for that row individually:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION archive_records(start_id bigint,
    end_id bigint)
RETURNS void
AS $$
  DECLARE
    _r    record;
  BEGIN
    FOR _r IN 
      SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > start_id AND id <= end_id
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO records_archive VALUES (_r.*);

        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
          -- Manipulate the _r.master_guid value, add some random
          -- numbers to it or whatever, and attempt reinsertion.
      END;
    END LOOP;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The problem is that `records` (and `records_archive`) are insanely wide tables.  I don't want to explicitly enumerate every single column to be copied from `_r` to `records_archive`, not only because I'm lazy, but because this stored procedure would become a dependency in any future column changes in those tables.

The problem I've got is that this doesn't work, syntactically or conceptually:

```
INSERT INTO records_archive VALUES (_r.*);
```

Neither do any of these:

```
INSERT INTO records_archive _r;
INSERT INTO records_archive _r.*;
```

Is there a way to pull this off?  If not, is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't see any straight forward way to accomplish what is basically a mutable insert statement with a mutating target table.  Aside from creating a brand new table every time you run that insert like SELECT * FROM source INTO TABLE0001. TABLE0001 being created as part of the select into.http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html

Comment: Well, yeah, I suppose I could use a temporary table or create a new one temporarily and then check all the GUIDs in that newly created table for collisions and then move them over.  But that seems more complicated than the suggestion to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a BEFORE INSERT Trigger on `records_archive`.  Do a select on the `records_archive` for the NEW.master_guid, and if it exists, manipulate it to add your random numbers.

You'd probably want a loop around the check to ensure the modified master_guid still didn't exist before went ahead with the insertion.

Comment: instead of a random value I suggest to get the max(master_guid)+1 value before to do the backup insert

Comment: It's a textual GUID, so MAX() isn't going to work.  But I'll figure that part out.  Thanks for the BEFORE INSERT trigger idea;  I hadn't thought of that.